# How to readjust Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

In my app, I have a custom layout that use Constraint Layout to display two views as follow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="444dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <CategorySelectionLayout
        android:id="@+id/categoryList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
    <CategoryNavigationLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/one_grid"
        tools:layout_manager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/order_selection_item"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now imagine when there's nothing to display inside categoryList, I'd like to hide it(View.GONE) then resize the constraint layout to only use the space required for navigation layout.

I have tried to set visibility inside custom view.

```
this.visibility = View.GONE
this.parent.requestLayout()
```

The view is now hidden but parent did not adjust the size accordingly.

So how do I force this ConstraintLayout to readjust it's size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you encounter is simply that your second view is constrained by the guideline -- as is the first view. The guideline itself is constrained to the container.

What that means is that it doesn't matter that you mark your first view as `GONE` -- yes, it will disappear, but this will not impact the layout at all:

- the guideline is constrained to the parent, so it doesn't care
- the view that is visible is constrained to the parent and the guideline,
  so doesn't care either.

So it's perfectly normal that nothing changes other than the view disappearing.

To do what you want, you could instead do something like that:

```
    final View viewA = findViewById(R.id.viewA);
    final View guideline = findViewById(R.id.guideline);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) guideline.getLayoutParams();
            if (viewA.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                viewA.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                params.guidePercent = 0.5f;
            } else {
                viewA.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                params.guidePercent = 0;
            }
            guideline.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });
```

This will change the position of the guideline, which will make the layout react.

I'm pasting the XML just to be exhaustive, but it's pretty much what you had:

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="303dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50248754" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewA"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewB"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:text="Toggle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/viewB"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/viewB" />
```

[image]